# I want to add a reaction to my embed but it doesnt really work.... [Discord.js v12.5]

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to add a reaction to this embed that is automatically sent to a specific channel after a user is done answering some questions. It's a discord application system. I believe I'm doing this right, since I've done this before the same way but now in this exact code, it doesn't work. This is my code :

````
 function send_finished(){
             let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setColor("#CD8BF2")
             .setTitle("A new Discord Helper application from: " + user.tag) 
             .setDescription(`${user}`)
             .setFooter(user.tag, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}))
             .setTimestamp()
             for(let i = 0; i < config.QUESTIONS.length; i++){
                 try{
                     embed.addField(config.QUESTIONS[i], '```' + String(answers[i]).substr(0, 1024) + '```')
                 }catch{
                 }
             }
 
 
             channel_tosend.send(embed);
             embed.react('✅')
 
             user.send("Thanks for applying to: " + message.guild.name)
       
         }
````

This is the error i get :

```
            embed.react('✅')
                  ^

TypeError: embed.react is not a function
```

Any help or actually telling me what the heck I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

message.channel.send({embed: embed});
message.channel.send({embed: embed}).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.react("");
});
```

Comment: tried it, doesnt work :/ Remember it's an application system in a function. I'm not sure what are the differences between that and a normal embed u send to a channel with a command for example

Comment: Are you trying to add the emoji to the description of the embed?

Comment: no, just add the reaction to the embed which later will have it's own function. Specifically to accept the application or decline it

Comment: ah. well check out my edited post, maybe it will help?

Comment: damn man! worked like a charm! I tried something similar to that before but i guess it was QUITE different because it was nothing close to working xD Thank u so much!!